# IQ test puzzle - sequence of shaded squares within a 3x3 grid

Tags: pattern, visual, sequence

The IQ test was pretty jokes until the last question

[image]

This one got me stumped.

Source: https://www.iqtestforfree.net/free-iq-test.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer might (there is often multiple solution in these kind of questions) be

> D

Explanation

> [image]
>  with the rules:
>  1: moves to the right one square every step
>  2: moves left one square every two steps
>  3: moves clockwise as the knight in chess every step
>  4: moves counter-clockwise only on corners every step

Comment: I had a hunch the answer was d because of the movement of the bottom two squares

Comment: Just could not see the logic of the top two

Comment: I was trying the same logic identifying the moves of each cube. but that knight move of chess :p making me illogical and also unable to figure out that more than one block can be moved to the same block holder.

Answer (score 2):

I think you all overthink it... how about just

> 4-3-4-4-3-4
> the answer is H

Comment: Haha like an analogy!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> G
>  Rules:
>  1: there is an integer sequence capturing the number of total coloured
>  squares: 4-3-4-4-3-3
>  2: there is an integer sequence capturing the maximum number of
>  connected coloured squares: 2-3-3-4-2-3
>  3: there is an integer sequence that captures the number of connected coloured squares: 3-1-2-1-2-1 it is not clear how it progresses from there onwards but it is clear that there is an alternation between some integer k and 1.